# Oauth with Custom Role Provider in asp.net mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oauth, thinktecture-ident-server, identityserver3

I am using Thinktecture Identity Server V3 (Oauth) for authentication with custom user store and I want to use role based authorization.

I am trying to use custom role provider to check for the roles. username attribute is null for IsInRole method. How can I add user data to current context?

Is it good idea to use RoleProvider in this case or add the roles as Claims? If I add them to Claims how can I use [Authorize] attribute? Do I need to write a custom Authorize attribute?

Answer (score 1):

The AuthorizeAttribute does work for authorization based on the role claim, but it sounds like your claims aren't being stored properly.

If this is the case, see this [Form Post client](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/Clients/MvcFormPostClient) (AccountController)  or this [OWIN/Katana client](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/Clients/MVC%20OWIN%20Client%20(Hybrid)) (Startup class) for good examples.

Also, roles should be considered and handled as a claim.

Thinktecture also have their own authorization manager package if you are interested. See [Dominick Baier's blog post](http://leastprivilege.com/2014/06/24/resourceaction-based-authorization-for-owin-and-mvc-and-web-api/) about this for more details.